# Python replace word with newline after a match

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.6, and I have a file that looks like this:

```
    interface Ethernet94
    profile users-1
    !
    interface Ethernet95
    profile users-admin
    !
    interface Ethernet96
    profile users-reg
    !
```

I want to have the option to replace the word that comes after 'profile' based on the interface number on the line above it.

So to change `interface Ethernet96` from `profile users-reg` to `profile users-all`, I have tried this:

```py
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import sys
    import fileinput
    filename = '/root/test'
    for line in fileinput.input([filename], inplace=True):
        if line.strip().startswith('interface Ethernet96\nprofile'):
            line = 'interface Ethernet96\nprofile users-all'
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

But this doesn't do anything to the file. I couldn't find a solution as all examples show how to replace word for word. But I cannot change the profile based on its name because I can have multiple interfaces with the same profile.

Please assist!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `regex` would do it nice

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

file = Path("file.txt")
content = file.read_text()
content = re.sub(r"(interface Ethernet96\nprofile) ([-\w]+)", r"\1 users-all", content)
file.write_text(content)
```

---

Replace the line using the indice of the `Ethernet96` row

```
from pathlib import Path

file = Path("file.txt")
content = file.read_text().splitlines()

row_idx = content.index("interface Ethernet96")
content[row_idx + 1] = "profile users-all"
```